# How to add heading inside excel using export excel in php

Tags: php, excel

I am using php to export data to excel.
How can I set custom heading before data inside excel?

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');
```

Comment: You do it in the bit where you create the actual data for your csv file

Comment: I can't able to center or bold the heading text when i give like that

Comment: No you can't.... you're creating a csv file.... csv files do not contain any formatting information such as alignment, bold, etc; just raw data.... if you want to add style information, then create a native BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format xls or xlsx file, not a csv file

Answer (score 0):

The PHPExcel plugin lets you create .xlsx files etc. using PHP and set the formatting of the output with the PHP script.  Plugin is available here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

I've found it fairly easy to setup but have had occasional timeout issues when working with large data sets.